# Set min/max for elements inside array in firebase rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Say I have data that looks like this:

```
{
  uid: "user",
  scores: [1,2,3]
}
```

I want to make sure the score is between `[1,4]`

The only thing i can think of is:

```
scores[0] >= 4 && scores[0] <= 1 && scores[1] >= 4 && scores[1] <= 1 && scores[2] >= 4 && scores[2] <= 1
```

but this gets really messy. Especially when we start going to lists with even greater sizes.

Is there anyway I could maybe use something like min/max to make the array bound?

Comment: Is `scores` sorted? Will it contain only integers?

Comment: It is integers only and is unsorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `scores` only contains integers and has a finite number of possibilities:

```
scores.hasOnly([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
```

(for 1 <= score <= 9)

Answer (score 1):

Firestore security rules don't currently offer any way to iterate an array, so what you're trying to do isn't possible except by indexing each item individually as you're doing now.  Your only real alternative to avoid iteration is to store each score in its own document in a subcollection, and write a different rule that checks each document's individual score.

You could of course instead require clients to only write scores through a backend API that you control.  The code for that endpoint can check the scores any way you like.